# How To Place One Forum Topic in Many Forums

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a forum system created with D6 and the Advanced Forum module. I would like to have a special forum topic posted in all the forum sections that describes the site rules and how to use the various forum features. It would be perfect if this could be done using a single node that appears in all forums at once because that way all the comments would be contained in a single discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered my own question. I used the Rules module (http://drupal.org/project/rules). That thing is GREAT!

First I created my topic that I wanted to show in all forums. Let's call it node/10.

Next I created a topic with the same title in all of the other forums, but the body content just reads, "REDIRECT". Let's call these nodes 11-16.

Then I created a new Triggered rule with one IF and one DO.

IF uses an "Execute custome PHP code" statement which checks the node id to see if it is one of the REDIRECT pages, like so...

```
return in_array($node->nid, array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16));
```

When IF returns true, DO immediately executes a System > Page redirect to node/10.

So far, so good.